# I keep getting this error and i can't seem to fix it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, function, oop, nomethoderror

I keep on getting
 `` in `eater': undefined method `hunger' for Human:Class (NoMethodError) ``

and this is the code i wrote :

```
   class Human
    attr_reader :name, :age, :hunger
    def initialize(name,age);
        @name = name
        @age = age
        @hunger = 50
    end 
    def eater() ;
        Human.hunger -= 10          
    end 
end

person = Human.new('Josh',32)
puts person.eater
```

basically i want to decrease the hunger of the person by 10 and then print the current amount of hunger but instead of printing it it  keeps on giving me this error,   I kind of used the concepts of OOP from python but even that doesn't seem to work,  I have tried almost everything and spent hours trying to get this can someone please help

Comment: Try self.hunger inside of your eater method

Comment: ^^ this is the answer

Comment: Don't put arbitrary semi-colons (`;`) in your Ruby code. These do nothing and they don't belong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to do:

```
class Human
  attr_reader :name, :age, :hunger

  def initialize(name, age, hunger = 50)
    @name = name
    @age = age
    @hunger = hunger
  end

  def eater
    @hunger -= 10
  end
end

person = Human.new('Josh', 32)
puts person.eater
```

Unless you want `@hunger` to always be `50` for all objects and not changed.

Don't set a default value as an instance variable on the object like you're doing with `@hunger = 50`. Instead, you want that default value to be in the parameters.

Also this `Human.hunger -= 10` should be `@hunger -= 10` because I'm assuming when you call `#eater` on the object you want it to decrement by `10`.

It appears you're not using any of the methods `attr_reader :name, :age, :hunger` gives you, you might as well get rid of that line as `attr_reader :name` is just a shortcut to:

```
def name
  @name
end
```